# F# winform handling click events

Tags: winforms, user-interface, f#

Hi I am doing a simple 2d drawing program in f#. What i want to do is add a form click event where i will add a Type DrawObject to a list of DrawObject. But the event need to return a unit but when i try to add the DrawObject to my list it will return a Drawobject list, how can i solve this.

```
let DrawObjectList: DrawObject list = []
let mouseClick = new System.EventHandler(fun _ _ -> (new DrawObject(...))::DrawObjectList)
form.Click.AddHandler(mouseClick);
```

This is what i have done so far.

Comment: The handler creates a new list and returns it. To update a `DrawObjectList` it must be mutable or be a reference. To return a unit use `ignore` function.

Comment: Also, the unit literal is simply `()`